# Adding a delay to jQuery's ScrollToFixed

Tags: jquery, html

I have a quick question regarding the jQuery plugin [ScrollToFixed](https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed). I have my NAV inside of my website. I applied a few lines of jQuery to 'stick' it on the top of the screen when the scroll reaches it. It works great.

What I would like to do is make a delay take place, with a fade in effect. Meaning, that when the scrolling hits the NAV menu, it takes 800 Milliseconds to appear on the screen. I have the following jQuery code in effect and I want to know if I am approaching this corectly.

What I have:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('nav').scrollToFixed();
 });
```

What I tried to insert to emulate the dealy and fade in:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('nav').scrollToFixed().delay( 800 ).fadeIn( 400 );
 });
```

At this point the ScrollToFixed still works, but the delay and fade in do not. Is there anything else I should try, am I doing it wrong? Maybe I do not fully understand the `.delay()` and `.fadeIn()` effects yet. Thanks for all the help Stack users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can't use `delay` like that (see [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/delay/)):

> the .delay() method allows us to delay the execution of functions that
>   follow it in the queue. It can be used with the standard effects queue
>   or with a custom queue.

An alternative would be to use `setTimeout` instead:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('header').scrollToFixed().fadeIn( 400 );
}, 800);
```

Comment: net.uk.sweet: Tried, to no avail. Still the same. Thank you though. =)

Comment: I even tried using `$('nav').delay(800).fadeIn( 400 ).scrollToFixed` and it did not work

Comment: Try using a setTimeout instead of the delay (see above).

Comment: net.uk.sweet: `setTimeout(function() {` worked great, thanks SO MUCH!